# Process a siml-csv file with AWK

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I've a file like this:

```
 "text I don't know" command other "text" 
 "some" different text "type"
```

I need to obtain "text I don't know" and "some", with sed, awk or whatever bash tool, to be piped to another command.

Any hint?

Comment: Give an example from your file, a small one. Also, is this homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems overly simple, which means you may be new to awk. Which is perfectly acceptable, or I misintreprted your question. I hope its the former.

The following should do what you ask. Setting the field separator to " `-F\"` (escape the " with ) and printing the second field, the first being to the left of ", or nothing. You can just put a pipe and the end of the line to do what you want.

`awk -F\" '{print FS$2FS}' inputFile.txt`

> "text I don't know"
>   "some"

FS is Field Seperator

Comment: all the answers were fine, but this is the "cleanest" :) thanks!

Comment: and btw I'm totally unaware of awk :-P

Comment: oh, no, you have to be aware of `awk` =P, for real its very useful, especially for basic text manipulation. I would highly suggest you spend a few minutes reading about its functionality, a lot of it is easier to learn as you go.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^\("[^"]*"\).*/\1/'
```

This deals with lines containing a simple double quoted field dropping any extra material.  It passes through any lines not matching that unchanged.

If you want to drop non-matching lines, then:

```
sed -n '/^\("[^"]*"\).*/s//\1/p'
```

This doesn't print by default and prints when it finds a match.

If you have to deal with data fields such as:

```
"He said, ""It's horrid""" and he meant it!
```

then you have to work considerably harder.  If your `sed` supports extended regular expressions or PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions), you can do it.  If not, use `awk` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `"` should be part of output or not, assuming not. If I'm mistaken, it shouldn't be any problems for you to add it to the output (deliberately left `sed` out of the list below, since the answer from @Jonathan-Leffler is a very good one)

Not a perfect solution since `"` is output as the first character, but it is simple.

```
cut -d\" -f1-2 input
```

Solution using pure bash, see [5.1 Bourne Shell Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) for explanation of `IFS`

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='"'

while read -ra LINE;
do
    echo ${LINE[1]}
done < input
```

Solution using awk, and the `-F` flag to change delimiter to `"`

```
$ awk -F\" '{print $2}' input
```

and finally one in perl. `-a` turns on autosplit mode – perl will automatically split input lines on whitespace into the `@F` array. `-F` is used in conjunction with -a, to choose the delimiter on which to split lines.

```
perl -F\" -lane 'print $F[1]' input
```